# How to get clicked item index in jQuery collection? Not by index()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get an index of clicked element

```
var $inputs = $("input");
$inputs.click(function() {
    console.log($(this).index())
});
```

it works well for following structure
`div>(input+input+input)`

But I need it for this case

`div>input
div>input
div>input`

Inputs are not siblings and I get the same index for each element. What is the simplest way to get that index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check index within the jQuery element collection by providing [element as an argument](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element) and apply [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element) method on element collection.

```
var $inputs = $("input");
$inputs.click(function() {
  console.log($inputs.index(this));
});
```

```js
var $inputs = $("input");
$inputs.click(function() {
  console.log($inputs.index(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input>
  <div>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input>
</div>
<div>
  <input>
</div>

<div>
  <input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.parent()`, for example:

```
$(this).parent().index();
```

`divs` with inputs must be wrapped in `div`

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).closest('div').index()`

https://api.jquery.com/closest/